# How to pass/get placeholder value?

Tags: php, placeholder

So I have a form where one entry is:

```
<input type="text" id="ptid" name="ptid" readonly="readonly" placeholder="<?php echo $pid; ?>">
```

The value of "$pid" is not null, I already got the value from database. Then I would like to get that value and pass to another php file. So I tried this code :

```
<?php
    $ptid=$_POST['ptid'];
?>
```

I tried printing this out, but somehow there's no result. Is there anyway to get the value?

Comment: post your full code for the form and any js/ajax if you are and db stuff since you did mention about a database (if relevant).

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hi pal - copy and paste your PHP code (with the HTML form you are using) & the copy of the database table structure and people will be along shortly to help :)

Comment: *"The value of "$pid" is not null"* - Yet now your code reads as `$ptid=$_POST['ptid'];`. and you already did another edit earlier in referencing the wrong POST array.

Comment: **Question is unclear**. You reading these comments at all? Edit: I guess you're not, or ignoring these and only checking for answers where you most likely won't comment on if they're wrong or not.

Comment: Voted to close as unclear.

Comment: If the question is solved, tick the checkbox next to the answer. Don't put "solved" in the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`placeholder`s aren't submitted as form values; that's the entire point of a `placeholder`: it *displays* in the input, but it is not treated as a value.

You'll need to use the regular `value="<?php echo $pid; ?>"` to submit the value with the form.

Comment: I agree with that comment, its unclear what the question is... xD

Comment: True. Now that certain someone retracted and changed their vote. And yeah, the question's too unclear  for my taste and the OP hasn't responded to comments.

Comment: More over, he hasn't provided how he is sending the POST. If it is not set then clearly, a) he hasn't declared that its a post or wrapped it in a form or b) something in his Javascript returns it 'false'.

Comment: [Seems I was right about this...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35775506/how-to-pass-get-placeholder-value#comment59222679_35775506) - as per [OP's comment in another answer...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35775506/how-to-pass-get-placeholder-value#comment59222998_35775605). amongst other comments. Instinct? Experience?

Comment: ah yes you're right ! i forgot to use value.
THANKS !!

Comment: @deceze and seems you were the one who was also right from the get go ;-)

Comment: @deceze Gotta love it when it looks all nice, shiny and new. Things are so much clearer ;-) good job on that *2 thumbs up*

Answer (score 2):

```
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="example">
<input type="submit" value="Post me!">
</form>
```

Ensure you're declaring the POST and if you want to a redirect the POST to another file for handling use `action`.

You're picking it up correctly however,

`$_POST['example'];` in this case.

This would POST the input to the same file so ensure the handler is in the same context. If you do not declare `post` it will assume its a `get` request.

If you want to catch the POST in the same context then what you're doing is right. If you want to POST it to another PHP file which handles it then you **cannot** catch it in the same context.

Hope that helped.

Comment: Actually, I already put <form method="post" action"destination.php">
I just highlight the input tags. So I think that's not the problem. 
I just want to catch the value of "$ptid" and pass to another file.

Comment: is destination.php in the same context or is that another file? If its another file, then that is where your issue is. You shouldn't need `action=".."` since you want to `POST` it to the same context. If you're passing it to another file, then you don't need to catch it in the same context... Your question is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of placeholder use value attribute

```
<input type="text" id="ptid" name="ptid" readonly="readonly" value="<?php if(isset($pid)) echo $pid; ?>">
```

You will get value on next page.

Because value is submitted not placeholder.

Answer (score -1):

I think that it's possible only with javascript - in HTML document you must create new hidden input and insert there a value with

> $("#ptid").attr("placeholder")